# Lost access to Solus Linux on my system after installing Manjaro KDE but I can still see the Solus data

Tags: linux, grub, dualboot

Until a few days ago I was using Solus as my sole distribution.

I decided to install Manjaro KDE a second distribution to try it out. Manjaro has been installed on my second hard drive, on a dedicated partition. I might have done a mistake during the installation, and I didn't select "install Manjaro along with my other distro" because I wanted to install it on a different disk.

The problem is that now, I cannot access my first distro (Solus), and only Manjaro is booting.

If I go to the UEFI, I have two booting options : Manjaro and UEFI-OS. But both are booting Manjaro.

I can access both hard drives and can see system files of both distributions.

Looking on the internet, it seems I have to do something with Grub, but I don't quite understand how to do it. Can you help me finding my way back to my old OS ?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, another forum has helped me.

The solution was to :

1. mount my Solus partition
2. install refind
3. I see Solus as a boot option on startup.